# Heroku: Unable to use git commands in pipeline

Tags: git, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a webpack project to Heroku. I wanted to have automatic build ids using something like this (in DefinePlugin in webpack.config.js#module.exports.plugins):

`BUILD_ID: JSON.stringify(childProcess.execSync("git rev-list HEAD --count").toString().trim().padStart(5, "0") + "." + childProcess.execSync("git rev-list HEAD -1 --abbrev commit").toString().trim()),`

This works as expected locally.

However, when I deploy this to Heroku, I get errors like this:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/tmp/build_88ed3d2c/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: Command failed: git rev-list HEAD --count
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
```

It appears that Heroku doesn't actually clone the repo as a git repository, so the commands fail and then my build fails.

Is there any workaround for this problem? Or does the thing I'm trying to do just not work?

Expected behavior: `git rev-list HEAD --count` and `git rev-list HEAD -1 --abbrev-commit` execute as if they were in a git repository, and the results are delivered to the BUILD_ID string.

Actual behavior: Heroku's build pipeline fails with the error above.

Edit: I've tried to do some stuff with `heroku-prebuild`, but have had no luck coming up with anything that actually solves this problem.

Comment: Possibly Heroku only does a shallow clone without any history? Thats a common problem for CI/CD tools.

Comment: This is likely the case, but I wouldn't know what to do with that in mind. I tried putting `git clone xxx` in heroku-prebuild, but its a private repository so that line doesn't work.